# When should I create a model in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I am just getting started with ASP.NET MVC. So far I like it a lot.
I am trying to get up to speed but I need some clarification. I want to know when should I create a model for the logic.
I mean so many times I found my self putting all logic into one "master" model. I know its not the right way to go.
But then again I'm not sure if it is good to have redundant properties in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking  about ViewModels, and it is perfectly fine to have different viewmodels instead of having one complex model even the properties are repeating. With master model, it tends to get complicated down the road. However, for special cases like CustomerCreateVM and CustomerEditVM, I would create the commmon properties in base class CustomerVM and inherit it and for more readability I will keep them in one file. Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your "View" model should accurately represent the information that is being shown/processed in that particular view. This means it should only have the fields that relate to the information being shown and nothing else. If it is not shown or used on the screen, it should not be in that model.